# Is there a difference in which enemy you choose to fight in hidden potential?

Tags: dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle

When you start a hidden potential, there are 3 paths that you can choose from.

Is there a difference in which one you pick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first enemy will net you more Small orbs

The second enemy will net you more Medium orbs

The third enemy will net you more Large orbs

The enemies are *slightly* more difficult based on which ones you fight, but not really.